# YouTube not playing

Tags: video, flash, browser, youtube, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. My Youtube isn't playing since three days. I upgraded the system. Re-installed Ubuntu restricted extras package. Still not working.

It's not working with any browser... I tried firefox, chrome.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the flash player plug-ins too? If you've not, use `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` to install..

Answer (score 4):

Same thing happened with me a while ago with my ubuntu 14.04 gnome, and got no particular answer from the community.

**What I did,**

After successful installation of `adobe-flashplugin` package, when I looked for flash plugin(which is `libflashplayer.so`) in mozilla plugin directory (`/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/`) it wasn't there.
So I copied the plugin from

```
/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
```

which i don't know why was there instead of `mozilla/plugins` directory.
So, I copied from this directory to `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugin/` and it worked for me.